# Render forms conditionally on checked radio button - Jinja2 templates - FastAPI

Tags: javascript, python, jinja2, fastapi

I'm pretty new to both *Jinja templating* and *javascript*; I'm trying to build an application in FastAPI which renders some Jinja templates.

I have added a pair of radio buttons to my template and I would like one of the two to trigger the rendering of a couple of *forms*.

Following the answer to [How to expose a form when a radio button is checked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60952260/how-to-expose-a-form-when-a-radio-button-is-checked), I've tried to proceed as such (I've defined the `.hidden` style in a proper `style.css` file):

```
...
<div class="row mt-5 mb-3">
        <div>
            <form method="post">
                <input type="radio" id="oneway-trip" name="trip-type" placeholder="One-way trip" checked/>
                <label>One-way trip</label>
                <br>
                <input type="radio" id="round-trip" name="trip-type" placeholder="Round trip"/>
                <label>Round trip</label>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
...
<div class="row mt-5 mb-3">
        <div>
            <form class="hidden" method="post">
                <input type="text" placeholder="from" name="dep-loc-cb" value="{{departure_location_comeback}}">
            </form>
            <form class="hidden" method="post">
                <input type="text" placeholder="to" name="arr-loc-cb" value="{{arrival_location_comeback}}">
            </form>
            <script>
                const form1 = document.querySelector("form[name='dep-loc-cb']");
                const form2 = document.querySelector("form[name='arr-loc-cb']");
                
                document.querySelector('#round-trip').addEventListener('change',(event)=>{
                if (event.target.checked){
                    form1.classList.remove("hidden");
                    form2.classList.remove("hidden");
                } else {
                    form1.classList.add("hidden");
                    form2.classList.add("hidden");
                }
                });
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Namely, I would like the radio button identified by `id='round-trip'` to trigger the rendering of the two forms identified by names `name='dep-loc-cb'` and `name='arr-loc-cb'`.

However, nothing is rendered whenever I click on the second radio button. I've tried to play around with my code on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/play and I've seen the following error being returned

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')

which would imply (I guess) the constant `form1` being null.

Can somebody help? Thank you!

Comment: You are targeting forms with names `dep-loc-cb` and `arr-loc-cb`, but none of your forms in the html have names. You do have inputs with these names; are you wanting the forms or inputs? You need to adjust your `document.querySelector()` calls accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

I'm new to js too.

But it seems that maybe you can try to add the 'action' attribute in the form to specify the URL or the web page to which the form data should be submitted when the user clicks the button.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).